# .Net - Aggregate tree lists in a special way using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have tree Lists of string (the amount of list can vary)

**list1**

A
B

**list2**

num1
num2
num3

**list3**

TT

**As a result i want List of this strings:**

A num1 TT
A num2 TT
A num3 TT
B num1 TT
B num2 TT
B num3 TT

So as you can see i want to join each string from one list with each string from other..

**How can i achive this in .Net using Linq? Is there a way?**

Comment: Do you need this to work on a fixed number of lists, or on a number dynamically chosen at runtime?

Comment: dynamically.. list is variable (as they count, so each list can have different about of items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
IEnumerable<string> MultiConcat(params IEnumerable<string>[] lists)
{
    if (lists == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (lists.Length == 0) {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    return lists.Aggregate(new[] { string.Empty } as IEnumerable<string>,
                   (acc, list) => acc.SelectMany(s1 => list.Select(s2 => s1 + s2)));
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
var list3 = new List<string> { "FOO", "BAR" };

foreach (var s in MultiConcat(list1, list2, list3)) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/xwu9d)**.

**How it works**

Basically it's just one call to `Enumerable.Aggregate`. The idea is that we have an enumerable collection of strings ("current") and another one ("incoming") we want to join it with. We do

```
current.SelectMany(s1 => incoming.Select(s2 => s1 + s2))
```

This is directly equivalent to

```
from var s1 in current
from var s2 in incoming
select s1 + s2
```

In other words, it produces the inner join of the two enumerables.

The beauty of `Aggregate` is that it allows us to perform this operation multiple times, processing multiple "incoming" collections one at a time.

Comment: @Ai_boy: HTH. `Enumerable.Aggregate` is ultra powerful -- remember it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an extension like:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T, F, S>(this IEnumerable<F> source, IEnumerable<S> second, Func<F, S, T> func)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in second)
            {
                yield return func(item, item2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
    var res = list1
              .Merge(list2, (f,s) => f + " " + s)
              .Merge(list3, (f,s) => f + " " + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from l1 in list1
from l2 in list2
from l3 in list3
select l1 + " " + l2 + " " + l3
```